# Not been able to get the exact coordinates of canvas when it is put in the draggable div

Tags: jquery, canvas, coordinates

Please check the fiddle. i got this plugin through answers. It works fine when the position of the canvas is fixed. But when i include the canvas in a draggable div and move the div the coordinates changes and hence i am not been able to draw anything. I want the pen touch to capture coordinates of canvas div and not page.

**JS Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/sVsZL/1/

Function not working:

```
function ev_canvas(ev) {
if (false) {
    ev._x = ev.touches[0].clientX;
    ev._y = ev.touches[0].clientY; // CH: Is there a better way to do this?
}
else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
    ev._x = ev.layerX;
    ev._y = ev.layerY;
}
else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
    ev._x = ev.offsetX;
    ev._y = ev.offsetY;
}

ev._x = ev._x + 0.5;
//ev._y = ev._y + 0.5;
// Call appropriate event handler
var func = PEN[ev.type];
if (func) {
    func(ev);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was looking for a similar solution for mouse positioning and I found it.
My canvas is positioned to the left and has a border. When I tried the same code you had it wasn't working either so I had to modify it. I don't know if it'll work for other purposes like dragging but maybe it will.

Replace:

```
   function ev_canvas(ev) {
if (false) {
    ev._x = ev.touches[0].clientX;
    ev._y = ev.touches[0].clientY; // CH: Is there a better way to do this?
}
else if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
    ev._x = ev.layerX;
    ev._y = ev.layerY;
}
else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
    ev._x = ev.offsetX;
    ev._y = ev.offsetY;
}
```

with:

```
function ev_canvas(ev) { 

     //Firefox
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) {
        ev._x = ev.layerX;
        ev._y = ev.layerY;
    // Any other browsers that may not use the above code
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) {
        ev._x = ev.offsetX;
        ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }
```

and then place a `<div>` around the `<canvas>` in **html** like this:

```
<div id="container">
<canvas id='canvas' width='1050' height='700'></canvas>
</div>
```

and then in **css** do this:

```
#container { position: relative; }
```